@Transactional() is not working for Snowfalke
Since Snowflake uses AutoCommit by default, I have set false while creating data sources in my application. Now for successful transaction also it is not storing in the DB.
If I remove prop.put("autocommit", false); then for unsuccessful transaction it is not rolling back
How to fix this, For RDBMS spring manages on it's  own

Can you please send us a sample of the code that you are using. Do you have "Begin Statement"  in your code ?

Looking at examples for JDBC Snowflake here
The way to set AutoCommit is connection.setAutoCommit(false), not by using properties. This should help you.

 String url = "jdbc:snowflake://<account_identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    props.put("user", "<user>");
    props.put("private_key_file", "/tmp/rsa_key.p8");
    props.put("private_key_file_pwd", "dummyPassword");
    props.put("db", "<database_name>");
    props.put("schema", "<schema_name>");
    props.put("warehouse", "<warehouse_name>");
    props.put("role", "<role_name>");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);
connection.setAutoCommit(false);

PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO t(c1, c2) VALUES(?, ?)");
pstmt.setInt(1, 101);
pstmt.setString(2, "test1");
pstmt.addBatch();

pstmt.setInt(1, 102);
pstmt.setString(2, "test2");
pstmt.addBatch();

int[] count = pstmt.executeBatch(); // After execution, count[0]=1, count[1]=1
connection.commit();


Please remember that DDL operations (Creating a table in this case) are commit-active. AutoCommit only works for DMLs. Refer to this doc for transaction statement rules
alter session set autocommit = false;

create table test._neeru.failure(
    test string
);

rollback;

select * from test._neeru.failure; -- table will be available


Thanks for the reply @neeru0303, is there b better way instead of manually committing.
I have a java code and i am using Transactional. It is not removing the saved changes if exception happens after storing in snowflake DB
